# How to display echo from register.php to index.php

Tags: php, email

I have index.php and register.php, concent.php file. I want index.php to display $msg (success / error) when I click on the button and check the email is correct or not.

index.php

```
<?php
include 'core/int.php'; //    $msg = ' ';
include 'includes/overall/header.php'; // header
include 'includes/overall/content.php'; // content
echo $msg;                                          // HOW TO DISPLAY SUCCESS OR ERROR??
include 'includes/overall/footer.php'; ?>
```

content.php

```
<form action="register.php" method="post">

<input type="text" name="email" class="input" placeholder="Address email"> &nbsp 
<input type="text" name="email_r" class="input" placeholder="Reply address"> &nbsp <input type="submit" name="register" class="button button-primary" value="REGISTER">

<aside class="log_reg3">

    <input type="checkbox" name="tems" value="tems"> I Accept TEMS &nbsp
        <a href="?register">Register</a> &nbsp Forgotten your <a href="recover.php?mode=username">username</a> and <a href="recover.php?mode=password">password</a>
</aside>
```

register.php

```
<?php include 'core/int.php'; // $db, $msg

if(!empty($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email_r']) && isset($_POST['email_r'])) {

    $email=($_POST['email']);
    $email_r=($_POST['email_r']);

    $regex = '/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/';

    if(preg_match($regex, $email)) {

                $msg = 'success';            }

    else {

        $msg = 'error';

                   }}?>
```

Comment: Are you just looking for `$_SESSION` for setting a value on one page and then displaying it on the next?

Answer (score 0):

you should put `$msg` in `$_SESSION['msg']` and try to access in index.php as

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['msg'])){
    echo $_SESSION['msg'];
    unset($_SESSION['msg']);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

index.php

```
<?php
include 'core/int.php';
include 'includes/overall/header.php'; 
include 'includes/overall/register.php'; // <---- add this
include 'includes/overall/content.php'; 
echo $msg;         
include 'includes/overall/footer.php'; ?>
```

and in content.php change action to index.php

```
<form action="index.php" method="post"> 

<input type="text" name="email" class="input" placeholder="Address email"> &nbsp 
<input type="text" name="email_r" class="input" placeholder="Reply address"> &nbsp <input type="submit" name="register" class="button button-primary" value="REGISTER">

<aside class="log_reg3">

    <input type="checkbox" name="tems" value="tems"> I Accept TEMS &nbsp
        <a href="?register">Register</a> &nbsp Forgotten your <a href="recover.php?mode=username">username</a> and <a href="recover.php?mode=password">password</a>
</aside>
```

in register.php remove `include 'core/int.php'; // $db, $msg`